# Show related entries without current entry

Tags: filter

I'm trying to show related entries to current entry by tag ID (which is working fine) but getting hung up when trying to exclude the current entry from the loop. I think I'm having an issue with paginate tags requiring an element criteria model but I'm not able to figure out how to get around this.

```twig
{% set segment = craft.request.lastSegment %}
{% for entries in craft.entries.slug(segment) %}
  {% set current = craft.entries.slug(segment) %}
  {% set tagId = entry.myTagFieldHandle.first() %}
  {% set suite = craft.entries.relatedTo(tagId) %}

    {% paginate suite|without(current) as entries %}
      {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endpaginate %}

{% endfor %}
```

Excluding the without filter on paginate outputs everything fine, but includes the current entry. I know there are probably better ways of doing this and I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're wanting to show a paginated list of related entries from a single entry page based on a tag relationship, correct?

This should point you in the right direction:

```
{% set segment = craft.request.lastSegment %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.slug(segment) %}

    {% set tagId = entry.myTagFieldHandle.first() %}

    {% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tagId).id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}

    {% paginate relatedEntries as related %}

        {% for entry in related %}

            {{ entry.title }}

        {% endfor %}

    {% endpaginate %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Now off to learn what ('not ' ~ entry.id) is all about...

Comment: The tilde in Twig converts all operands into strings and concatenates them thus excluding said entry id from the relationship. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ryan, I definitely have a lot to learn both regarding Craft and Twig. Every comment and solution is a huge help.